# Warnings from W3C validation for CSS: "can't find the warning message for vendor-extension"

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I am getting a lot of warnings in all my websites CSS's when I test them with the W3C tool http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/. I passed without errors, but a lot of warnings that say:

> can't find the warning message for vendor-extension

What does this means and how could I solve it?
I searched in Google without good answers.

Comment: Short answer: *Let it be* :) that's probably because of using vendor-prefixes' CSS properties.

Answer (score 3):

You asked 2 questions, let's try to answer your questions if possible..

First of all you didn't post the lines of your CSS code that returned the W3C validation feedback so I add a common example below.. You might want to edit your question and add the style that isn't W3C valid if you need an answer to the Vendor error. However I hope my answer will be helpful as well.

Lets see.. If you use vendor styles from Firefox, Microsoft or any other vendor that is not available in the W3C standards you will get this kind of warning or error messages.

For example I used the firefox styles like `-moz-border-radius` this is a Vendor style from firefox and will result in a warning from the W3C validation test. The Microsoft style `ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true)` will result in the same warning as well, there are a lot of styles from vendors that never will be supported by W3C, it's supported by the vendors browser or applications only and sometimes in multiple browsers...

2 code examples that will result in a warning:

```
    fieldset
   {
  -moz-border-radius: 7px; /* This is a vendor extension that can send a warning like "can't find the warning message for vendor-extension" */
  border: 1px #6B0c0c solid;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 550px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  }
```

an other example, I wanted to remove outline in MSIE:

```
    a, a:active, a:focus, a img {
    outline: none;
    ie-dummy: expression(this.hideFocus=true); /* Remove outline in MSIE - Microsoft Internet Explorer 9 - This is a vendor extension that can send a warning like "can't find the warning message for vendor-extension" */
    }
```

Well, the answer to your question on what it means is: It's no standard W3C CSS code so W3C does not support and returns a warning. it's no bug just not supported by W3C.

The answer to your question on how to solve it:  If you want to keep your CSS W3C valid, I'd say look for valid css code that IS supported by W3C and can do what you want. If not available remove and don't use the code that is not supported by W3C. pages with CSS lines with vendor warnings are a validation problem but browser will ignore the lines of CSS if not supported..

Again: If you're able to add the lines of CSS to your question: I will add information that will answer your question better and don't forget to tell what the CSS should change on your pages, maybe we can offer some valid code to solve your problem

Answer (score 2):

It means that there is a bug in the W3C CSS Validator; [report the bug](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/Email.html), providing sufficient details so that it can be reproduced. (I do not get such a message when using vendor extensions.)

Answer (score 1):

All that starts with one of the following:

```
-o-
-ms-
-moz-
-webkit-
```

results in the error message mentioned;

> can't find the warning message for vendor-extension

as [Hashem Qolami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1725764/hashem-qolami) stated earlier [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21889767/warnings-from-w3c-validation-for-css-cant-find-the-warning-message-for-vendor#comment33147026_21889767)   in **this** topic.

If you can avoid using them, the problem is solved.